# How to get current password age for a user using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I've been reading through boto 3 documentation to find this feature, but I can't seem to locate it.

I'd like to get the current password age, like the one you can see in the aws IAM console.

I was under the impression that `get_login_profile`'s "CreateDate" should give me the age for the current password, but it turns out that `get_login_profile` only returns the create date of the very first password you set up (so basically the day you made your account "console accessable"), not the age of the current password.

This means that if you've changed password for any reason, you can't rely on `CreateDate`.

Is this feature not supported by boto3 natively? Or am I missing something here? I could maybe use AWS lambda to alert me every time a user's password changes, but that seems like too much work for such a simple feature.

Any help is much appreciated.

Here's what I've tried:

```
try:
    password_age = iam_client.get_login_profile(UserName=ind["UserName"])
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        password_age = None
if password_age:
        ind["password_age"] = password_age.get('LoginProfile', {}).get("CreateDate", {})
```

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/jchrisfarris/aws-account-automation/blob/master/lambda/ExpireUsers.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The age of an IAM User's password does not appear to be accessible via any API call.

However, it is supplied as `password_last_changed` in the [Credentials Report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_finding-unused.html) that can be downloaded from the AWS IAM management console.

Comment: too bad this isn't a feature... guess I'm going the lambda or trail log route. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: aws iam list-users --query "Users[?UserName=="<user>"].PasswordLastUsed"

should give the timestamp when the password was last changed

Comment: @Shiv Not quite. Rather than being the last _changed_ date, `PasswordLastUsed` is "the date and time when the user's password was last used to sign in to an AWS website. For a list of AWS websites that capture a user's last sign-in time, see the Credential Reports topic in the Using IAM guide. If a password is used more than once in a five-minute span, only the first use is returned in this field."